# How to remove a non-existing GitHub Ansible role from Galaxy?

Tags: github, ansible-galaxy

[According to this documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html#remove-an-installed-role) it is possible to remove a role from [Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/), but the following fails:

- `ansible-galaxy login` succeeded
- `ansible-galaxy delete 030 https://github.com/030/ansible-firewall` resulted in:

> ERROR! Galaxy user 030 does not have access to repo 030/https://github.com/030/ansible-firewall

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass only the repository not the full HTTP URL of the repository when you want to delete it from what I've read in the documentation. So the command should be:

```
ansible-galaxy delete 030 ansible-firewall
```